# Print object of variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
$server = "abc"
$t = "Invoke-sqlcmd -serverInstance $sqlinst -Database "master" -Query $a | select name,value |select -skip 1"

$out = $server + "," $t.name + "," +$value
```

This code is not printing the object of `invoke-sqlcmd`.

Please help me get the correct value in `$out` to print the object

Comment: $t is a string, not an invokable method...remove the quote from start and end of $t assignment. `$t = Invoke-sqlcmd -serverInstance $sqlinst -Database "master" -Query $a | select name,value `. Also, last $value shout be $t.value

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do since some of the variables used is missing but below should work.
Basically you have put the entire Invoke-sqlcmd as a string and that wont execute it.

```
$server = "abc"
$output = Invoke-sqlcmd -serverInstance $server -Database "master" -Query $a

$result = $output | Select-Object -Property name,value -Skip 1
Write-Output "$server $result"
```